# sinon and mocha - stubbing private dependencies

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, sinon

I have a node express app, and I'm writing some tests for it with mocha, chai and sinon. I have a module that contains endpoint handlers. It roughly looks like this:

```
var db = require('./db-factory)();

module.exports = {
   addUser: function(req, res) {
       if (req.body.deviceID === undefined) {
           res.status(400).json({ error: 'deviceID is missing' });
           return;
       }      

       db.save(req.body, function(err) {
           // return 201 or 500 based on err
       });
   }
}
```

I would like to stub the `db.save` call to return a 201 status, but as you can see, the `db` is an internal dependancy. What needs to be done to make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried stubbing it in your test? If normal stubbing doesn't work due to the way you have your db exporting, try rewire:

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const rewire = require('rewire');

var myModule = rewire('./myModule');

describe('myModule', () => {
    it('should test myModule', () => {
        let fake = {
            save: () => {
                console.log('stub save')
                //return whatever you want 
            }
        }

        myModule.__set__('db', fake);
        //db.save in your module should now call the fake function
    });
})
```

myModule is the module with the end points. This should replace the entire db module in myModule.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the unit test solution using additional library `proxyquire` for stubbing the `./db-factory` module.

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
const db = require("./db-factory")();

module.exports = {
  addUser: function(req, res) {
    if (req.body.deviceID === undefined) {
      res.status(400).json({ error: "deviceID is missing" });
      return;
    }

    db.save(req.body, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.sendStatus(500);
      }
      res.sendStatus(201);
    });
  },
};
```

`./db-factory.js`:

```js
function Factory() {
  const db = {
    save() {},
  };
  return db;
}

module.exports = Factory;
```

`index.spec.js`:

```js
const sinon = require("sinon");
const proxyquire = require("proxyquire");

describe("49095899", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });
  describe("#addUser", () => {
    it("should save user correctly", () => {
      const dbStub = { save: sinon.stub().yields(null) };
      const handlers = proxyquire("./", {
        "./db-factory.js": sinon.stub().returns(dbStub),
      });
      const mReq = { body: { name: "a", age: 25, deviceID: "1" } };
      const mRes = { status: sinon.stub(), sendStatus: sinon.stub() };
      handlers.addUser(mReq, mRes);
      sinon.assert.calledWith(dbStub.save, mReq.body, sinon.match.func);
      sinon.assert.calledWith(mRes.sendStatus, 201);
    });

    it("should send status 500 if save user failed", () => {
      const mError = new Error("save user error");
      const dbStub = { save: sinon.stub().yields(mError) };
      const handlers = proxyquire("./", {
        "./db-factory.js": sinon.stub().returns(dbStub),
      });
      const mReq = { body: { name: "a", age: 25, deviceID: "1" } };
      const mRes = { status: sinon.stub(), sendStatus: sinon.stub() };
      handlers.addUser(mReq, mRes);
      sinon.assert.calledWith(dbStub.save, mReq.body, sinon.match.func);
      sinon.assert.calledWith(mRes.sendStatus, 500);
    });

    it("should send status 400 if deviceId is missing", () => {
      const handlers = require("./");
      const mReq = { body: { name: "a", age: 25 } };
      const mRes = { status: sinon.stub().returnsThis(), json: sinon.stub() };
      handlers.addUser(mReq, mRes);
      sinon.assert.calledWith(mRes.status, 400);
      sinon.assert.calledWith(mRes.json, { error: "deviceID is missing" });
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
  49095899
    #addUser
      ✓ should save user correctly
      ✓ should send status 500 if save user failed
      ✓ should send status 400 if deviceId is missing


  3 passing (24ms)

---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |      100 |      100 |       90 |      100 |                   |
 db-factory.js |      100 |      100 |       50 |      100 |                   |
 index.js      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.spec.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/49095899